# Does Frank automation framework provide screenshot capture option for failure scenario?

Tags: ios, cucumber, automated-tests

I am aware that Frank tool provide option for capturing screenshot. But it is a user defined step.

Taking a screenshot of the app:

```
Then /^I save a screenshot with prefix (\w+)$/ do |prefix|
 filename = prefix + Time.now.to_i.to_s
 %x[screencapture #{filename}.png]
end
```

But is there any other possibility of by default saving the screenshot in case of unexpected test failure ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the application is still open, you could use an After hook to call the Frank step that takes screenshots if the test failed.

Try this:

```
After do |scenario|
    if scenario.failed?
        steps %Q{
            Then I save a screenshot with prefix test
        }
    end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin, u've made my day